# Why UDF call with declared variables as parameters is ways faster than call with hardcoded parameters

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm having the following, in my opinion, very strange problem. When I call a **UDF** the following way:

```
DECLARE @contact_id uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @group_id uniqueidentifier
SET @group_id = 'EE57E2AD-204B-4078-AFA4-11FA8375C2FD'
set @contact_id = 'E6EFCC9F-9D1C-4C38-A950-C45372F2A6D2'

SELECT COUNT( ID )  AS [CountAll] 
FROM [Document] As [Document] 
WHERE ([Document].[ID] IN (SELECT ID FROM [fs_Document_View_ee57e2ad_204b_4078_afa4_11fa8375c2fd](@contact_id, @group_id)))
```

It runs for 4s and I get the following execution plan:  [fast](http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=28e812712e)

When I call the **UDF** with hard coded parameters as this:

```
SELECT COUNT( ID )  AS [CountAll] 
FROM [Document] As [Document] 
WHERE ([Document].[ID] IN (SELECT ID FROM [fs_Document_View_ee57e2ad_204b_4078_afa4_11fa8375c2fd]('E6EFCC9F-9D1C-4C38-A950-C45372F2A6D2', 'EE57E2AD-204B-4078-AFA4-11FA8375C2FD')))
```

I get this execution plan: [slow](http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=3c0013a7b6) and it takes 91s.

Can anyone explain me why this is happening?

The function calls 4 other nested functions passing the them the same parameters. It's related with items view permissions.

Thanks for the help in advance.

**UPDATE**

I used Option 2 from [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/) which Ivan G. mentioned.

The problem is parameter sniffing and option 2 solved the problem.

> Another method of resolving the parameter sniffing issue is to disable parameter sniffing >altogether.  This is not done with a switch or database option, but can be done from >within the script of  your stored procedure code.  Here is an example of how I created my >stored procedure so parameter sniffing is disabled:

```
DROP PROC [dbo].[DisplayBillingInfo]
GO
CREATE PROC [dbo].[DisplayBillingInfo]
  @BeginDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME;
DECLARE @StopDate DATETIME;
SET @StartDate = @BeginDate;
SET @StopDate = @EndDate;
SELECT BillingDate, BillingAmt
  FROM BillingInfo
  WHERE BillingDate between @StartDate AND @StopDate;
```

> To disable parameter sniffing, all I did was to change the way the
>   parameter values were used within the stored procedure.  By creating
>   two different local variables (@StartDate and @EndDate) inside my
>   procedure, setting those variables to the passed parameters, and then
>   using the local variables in the BETWEEN condition, I was able to
>   disable parameter sniffing.  Parameter sniffing is disabled because
>   the optimizer is not able to identify the parameters’ values in the
>   actual SELECT statement.  Because SQL Server cannot tell what
>   parameter values where used to call the stored procedure, the
>   optimizer creates a generic plan based on the statistics.
>
> When I execute my stored procedure using the code above, using either
>   a narrow range of dates or a years’ worth of dates, the compiled
>   execution plan always does an “index scan” operation.  I can tell
>   parameter sniff is turned off because I know that the short range of
>   dates would normally have created an index seek operation.

Comment: The link to the fast version points to the slow version of the query plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is due to the parametrization. First version of your query is parametrized, and the second one isn't. "*Queries which are parametrized requires less recompilation and dynamically built queries needs compilations and recompilation very frequently*" ([source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/25/sql-server-2005-forced-parameterization-and-simple-parameterization-t-sql-and-ssms/))

For version of query built with parameters, execution plan is created and then reused: "*If a SQL query has parameters, SQL Server creates an execution plan tailored to them to improve performance, via a process called 'parameter sniffing'. This plan is stored and reused since it is usually the best execution plan*" ([source](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/)).